# How to get spplaylist id?

Tags: cocoalibspotify-2.0

How do I have id of spplaylist ?

currently it returns

```
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@ (%@ items)", [super description], [self name], [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[[self valueForKey:@"items"] count]]];
```

because of [self name] it contains it returns playlist name. What to do if I want it to return spplaylist id?

For playlist name keyvalue is @"name" , may I know what is the key value for id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique identifier for a playlist is its URI, which can is in the `spotifyURL` property of all metadata objects, including `SPPlaylist`.